# Add restrictions to WCF in method/data member

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web-services

I'm new to WCF and I try to add restriction to data member.

For exmple in this method:

```
[DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
```

I want to set max and min length. I know how to add the restriction to the XML code

```
 <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:minLength value="2"/>
  <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

but is there a way to add a restriction straight from the code?

Comment: You may have to use the XMLSerializer instead if you want that level of control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx), maxLength, minLength and length etc are ignored. There is no declarative way to enforce what you're asking for, as much as I wish there was. This is one of those places where the cracks between the .NET and XML worlds show. The only method I've found for enforcement is to build a [message inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) and apply the transform in there.

Comment: Also based on message inspector [How to: Perform Message Validation with Schema Validation in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647820.aspx)

Comment: great link, I was looking for something more explicit like that

Answer (score 1):

Use http://wcfdataannotations.codeplex.com/

Possible duplicates of the question:

[DataMember attributes for Data validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897916/datamember-attributes-for-data-validation)

[How should I validate parameters passed into my WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835455/how-should-i-validate-parameters-passed-into-my-wcf-service/10839767#10839767)

Comment: This question is OLDER than the others that you references