# How should I validate parameters passed into my WCF service?

Tags: wcf, validation

Normally you check incoming parameters in your public methods using `if-then-throw`  pattern or Code Contracts.
My question is, how should I validate parameters passed in my WCF service? For example, I've got the following contract:

```
[OperationContract]
Stock GetStock(string symbol);
```

I want to ensure that `symbol`parameter is not `null` or empty string. Should I use the same `if-then-throw` pattern or Code Contracts precondition on the service-side? Should I add a `FaultContract` attribute to the `GetStock` method and return a fault to the client? What's the best parameters validation technique for WCF service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enterprise Library [Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664356%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) has an adaptor for [integration with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664526%28v=pandp.50%29) designed for exactly this.

This [CodeProject Introduction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18667/Introduction-to-Validation-Application-Block-integ) is a little old but gives a bit more background than the MSDN links.

Comment: Can `Data Annotaion` do this job?

Comment: You can use it for validation, but its in a different technology stack from WCF. System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is for ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET data controls.

Comment: For anybody getting a "operation.SyncMethod" error with VAB and WCF, VAB does not seem to support **async**, alternatively look at [Validating wcf service operations using system.componentmodel.dataannotations](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/validating-wcf-service-operations-using-system.componentmodel.dataannotations)